# Retrofit2: Kotlin POST request with JSON data returning 400

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit2 instead of raw HttpUrlConnection for my app so I'm testing it and I found first basic problem with it.

I'm trying this on Reques.in testing API to pass json data to it, but its returning HTTP code 400.

```
object AppAPI {

    private const val baseUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}

interface ApiRegisterUser {
    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8"
    )
    @POST("register")
    suspend fun registerUser(@Body userData: UserRegisterData) : Response<UserRegisterResponse>
}

data class UserRegisterData(
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("password") val password: String
)
```

Response:

```
response: error: response: Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://reqres.in/api/register}
```

So I figured out Error there:
There is specific Error in `response.errorBody()`

```
Note: Only defined users succeed registration
```

But not sure what does it mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, it looks like this dummy REST API server only supports predefined e-mail addresses for the `/register` endpoint, see the "Hello ReqRes users!" section on https://reqres.in/ for the predefined users.

So using for example `eve.holt@reqres.in` as e-mail address seems to work. The password apparently does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/` to end of the path, usually HTTP 400 refers to bad request from client side which might be either URL or the Body content is not matching with what server is expecting, did you try the same with curl?

```
 @POST("register/")
 suspend fun registerUser(@Body userData: UserRegisterData) : Response<UserRegisterResponse>
```

Comment: tried to add / to the end but same result. I don't know what else is server expecting. I checked reqres.in POST REGISTER request and my JSON Data class is matching what is expected. There are just 2 parameters. Nothing complicated